# Can't click on any links in my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a small website with bootstrap for a gaming clan of mine:
[karmaclan.ch](https://karmaclan.ch/)

The problem is that every link is unclickable. 
All hrefs are set and you can get to the links with a click on the 
middle mousekey.

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: That web site is just video. Can you show us a code example?

Comment: You can scroll down if you want :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `preventDefault` behavior in your `js/javascript.js` file. Remove it.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!